# Flutter Maps live location crashes because live location is not a Future<dynamic> how do you fix?

Tags: dart, flutter, location, maps, future

I started working on a flutter project where i have to use google maps and a persons live location to bring them to a certain place. I got google maps on the screen but when i started to add live location it crashes. I also have a screen with a standard location but since the live location crash this screen crashes/closes the whole app.

On the live location screen i now get a red screen with: 'Future is not a subtype of type 'CameraPosition'. I also have this error on visualstudio code: Unable to open 'libobject_patch.dart': Cannot read property 'create' of undefined.

I use google maps and location dependencies.

I tried using try on, but it gets the location(checked with breakpoints) but then it doesnt return the right data (it returns as a future)

This is the code i use in the classes. It is a bit messy, this is my first flutter project.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';


//deze functie werkt, hij vindt de locatie als al is toegestaan
//ook wordt er gevraagd om de locatie als deze nog niet is gegeven
//daarna pas de error
  GoogleMapController myController;
  Location location = new Location();
  _animateToUser() async{
    location.onLocationChanged();
    try{
      LocationData pos = await location.getLocation();
        myController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude),
            zoom: 12.0,
          )
        )
      );
    }
    on Exception{
      final CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(52.0575, 4.49306),
      zoom: 12.0,
      );
    }
  }

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    GoogleMapController myController;
    Location location = new Location();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("P-App"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 200.0,
              height: 10.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    _animateToUser();                    
                    Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VindLocatie()),
                    );
                  //invoeren naar de pagina met maps waar gebruiker om locatie wordt gevraagd
                  },
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  textColor: Colors.blue,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "Zoek met uw locatie",
                  ),
            ),
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 200.0,
              height: 10.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EigenLocatie()),
                  );
                },
                elevation: 5.0,
                textColor: Colors.blue,
                color: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "Zoek met opgegeven locatie",
                  ),
            ),
            ),
          ],
        )
        )
    );
  }
}

class VindLocatie extends StatelessWidget{

  GoogleMapController myController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("P-App"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 350.0, //Manier vinden om voor de helft te zetten ( misschien met percentages ofzo)
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child:GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.hybrid,
              initialCameraPosition: _animateToUser(),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                myController = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the live location of the user.
The actual result is a redscreen with the future is not a subtype of CameraPosition.

Comment: did you find solution for this ?

Comment: @AnkeshKumar Yes. Would you like the improved code or the solution of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, you have to change the future. its like the same as an await statement. If you want the updated version just ask me, but I have to search for it because its a while ago